# JSON path to fetch value on a different node conditionally

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

On the below JSON example, I need to get only 1 ID when `'contenttype'!='helptext'`

I cannot do `'contenttype'=='textAreaSelectionLong'` because a lot of other types are possible.

Since it's on a different node on the same level as id, I don't know how to write it in a single JSON path expression.

I tried the below JSON path,

```
$.children[?(@.name=='p')].children[?(@.name=='@id')].text
```

And it gives me,

```
[
  "id2",
  "id3"
]
```

But I am expecting a JSON path that could return only `id2`

Below is a chunk of JSON that this example is based on,

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "@id",
            "text": "id1",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "contenttype",
            "text": "question",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "p",
            "text": "Some random text 1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "contenttype",
                    "text": "textAreaSelectionLong",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "@id",
                    "text": "id2",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "p",
            "text": "Some random text 2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "@id",
                    "text": "id3",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "contenttype",
                    "text": "helptext",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Could anyone tell me if the below JSON path makes sense. Just an **update** to the above JSON path?

`$.children[?(@.name=='p' && @.children[?(@.name=='contenttype')].text!='helptext')].children[?(@.name=='@id')].text`

Apparantly, jsonpath.com doesn't seem to properly parse this and give me the expected result. I know that it logically makes sense. But, is the syntax fine?

Comment: Did this one work? `$..[?(@.text== 'Some text 1')]..[?(@.name=='@id')].text`

Comment: Unfortunately no. The `Some text 1` is also random. So, I cannot tie that up to the condition as well. Only object that could be used in a condition is `name`

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 `helptext` is one of the values I want to avoid while fetching the data. So, only to do that, we may use something like `[?(@.text != 'helptext')]`. Let me know if you have any other suggestions

Comment: You can get all `text` by JsonPath then remove 'helptext' after that. I have no idea to achieve the goal with only JsonPath.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 Thanks for the suggestion. However, I would really need to achieve this using JSON path as I have a constraint to use Azure Data Factory for ETL. It is configured to map based on JSON paths only.

Comment: Use [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) to test online if you are using java port of jsonpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Jayway JsonPath java port](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) you can use the [Filter Operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) `nin`

**JSONPath**

```
$.children[?('helptext' nin @.children[*].text)].children[?(@.name=='@id')].text
```

Online Test Tool : [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your expressions assume that it's available on a fixed node position. It's however not possible in the JSON that I receive. Anyway, leaving this question open to see if someone is able to suggest an answer or approach.

Comment: @GiftsonDavid if you are using java port (Jayway jsonpath), check my updated answer. It should work

Comment: Thanks Akshay for the updated answer. It serves my purpose. I've accepted it too.